# ffmpeg Unrecognized option 'tune'

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg on node.js. And option '-tune zerolatency' for low latency

But when I insert "-tune zerolatency",  I get an error: Unrecognized option 'tune'.

Can anyone help? I have no idea what to do.

Here's the script.

```
let token = '@!#!@#%@$@#%#^^!@$@#$@#$@#$^@#$'
let option = [
    '-i', 'pipe:0', //mpeg4
    '-acodec', 'copy',
    '-vcodec', 'copy',
    '-s', '284x164',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-tune', 'zerolatency',
    '-f', 'flv',
    'rtmp://localhost:1935/s/' + token,
];
ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", option);

ffmpeg.stdin.write(streaming_data);
```

Here's the ffmpeg version

```
ffmpeg version N-82166-g894e7ef Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tune` is a private option of certain encoders, not a common option. Since you are copying the video stream over, no encoder is invoked, and so the option isn't recognized. Similar is true of the size and preset options, although those are common options and they are simply inert instead of unknown in this command.

If you change `'-vcodec', 'copy'` to `'-vcodec', 'libx264'`, all three options will take effect. But this will transcode the video, so time and CPU use will *increase*.

Comment: I've changed '-vcodec', 'copy' to '-vcodec', 'libx264'
but same error 
Unrecognized option 'tune'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Comment: Your ffmpeg build does not have libx264 compiled. You need a build with it.